# Left and right space or padding with inline svg in internet explorer 9 to 11

Tags: html, image, css, svg

I have an inline SVG and somehow internet explorer shows some sort of margin, padding, border or space to the left and right of my svg.

The svg covers the entire viewport width. Which means I have

```
<div class="head"> 

    <img src="head.svg">

</div>
```

and here my css:

```
.class img { position:absolute; top:0; width:100%; border:0; margin:0; padding:0 0 10% 0;}
```

What is going on? this only happens in internet explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max-width and it will solve your problem. Make sure to also set the height to 100%

Comment: Nice one, max-width removes the left & right padding. Unfortunately in IE11 using height: 100%; sets the height way too high.